# mariadb check value exists in json field

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have mariadb table to allow user entering a room, im using json format in `allowed_user` field that contain iduser who allow to enter a room.

```
| idroom | room_name    | allowed_user          |
| ------ | ------------ | --------------------- |
| 1      | Living Room  | {"1","2","3","4","5"} |
| 2      | Dining Room  | {"2","3"}             |
| 3      | Kitchen      | {"3"}                 |
| 4      | Utility Room | {"4"}                 |
```

my question is how to filter data, using allowed_user field by json value = 3

Comment: Storing "ID's" like that in a RMDB is bad design, you should create a table `user_per_room`,. This way you would be able to write a proper query to test which users have access to the room

Comment: Where is the connection to json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://dbfiddle.uk/V89es2ro

```
CREATE TABLE `tableName` 
(
    `idroom`    INT,
    `room_name` VARCHAR(512),
    `allowed_user`  VARCHAR(512)
);

INSERT INTO `tableName` (`idroom`, `room_name`, `allowed_user`) VALUES ('1', 'Living Room', '["1","2","3","4","5"]');
INSERT INTO `tableName` (`idroom`, `room_name`, `allowed_user`) VALUES ('2', 'Dining Room', '["2","3"]');
INSERT INTO `tableName` (`idroom`, `room_name`, `allowed_user`) VALUES ('3', 'Kitchen', '["3"]');
INSERT INTO `tableName` (`idroom`, `room_name`, `allowed_user`) VALUES ('4', 'Utility Room', '["4"]');

SELECT * FROM `tableName` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`allowed_user`, '"3"');
```

Comment: omg... double quote inside single quote... thx very much...